# Adding braces for If-else using Uncrustify

Tags: if-statement, uncrustify

I was wondering if there is any way to add braces in nested If-else using Uncrustify. For example:

```
if( stat_error == -1 ){
   if ( debug > 0 )
      printf( "...ERROR ); //I would like to add braces around here.
   exit( -1 );
} else {
```

I have seen this:

```
# Add or remove braces on single-line 'if' statement. Will not remove the braces if they contain an 'else'.
mod_full_brace_if                        = add   # ignore/add/remove/force
```

But it doesn't seem to work for nested conditionals.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

My experience with Uncrustify in your example :

> Add or remove braces on single - line `if` statement. Will not remove the braces if they contain an `else`.

```
mod_full_brace_if = add
```

> Make all `if` / `elseif` / `else` statements in a chain be braced or not. Overrides `mod_full_brace_if`.
>
> If any must be braced, they are all braced. If all can be unbraced, then the braces are removed.

```
mod_full_brace_if_chain = false
```

And it worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

you need to add a return statement should look like this

```
    if( stat_error == -1 ){
   if ( debug > 0 )
      printf( "...ERROR ); //I would like to add braces around here.
   exit( -1 );
} else{

Insert else statement
}
return statement here
}
```

Comment: I don't understand it. Why should I add that?

Comment: This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question asked.